# How to query registry rights on a key using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, registry

Need to query a specific key in the HKLM hive for security permissions.  We do not want to change the permissions, just log them to a file. To start I would be satisfied with using WriteLine or a msgbox to display the permissions on the key.  I'm new to VB.net. I can't find an example of querying keys only adding them, modifying permissions.  Can RegistryRights.FullControl be used to return True or False? If so, can someone provide a link online that has a good example?

I have searched for hours online and have tried to modify the examples here to only perform a query on a key, but I cannot create a query on registry key permissions.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.registryrights?view=netframework-4.8

Here is a sample of code to attempt permission changes. But we want to query, not change permissions.

```
' Prevent the current user from writing or changing the
' permission set of the key. Note that if Delete permission
' were not allowed in the previous access rule, denying
' WriteKey permission would prevent the user from deleting the 
' key.
rs.AddAccessRule(New RegistryAccessRule(user,
    RegistryRights.WriteKey Or RegistryRights.ChangePermissions,
    InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Deny))
```

Expected output would be something like this where the field is True or false or 983103 or some other value:

```
Console.WriteLine("Regkey rights on HKLM\Software\wow6432node\somekey\ " & RegistryRights.FullControl)
```

Comment: Have you looked into the [`RegistryKey.GetAccessControl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8) method?

Comment: Jeff, I appreciate your help very much.  I'm not a developer. I've written numerous scripts (batch, VB5, VBS, PERL, PHP, some C, etc.) and my programming training was back in the 80's (Fortran and VB)!! So I don't understand how to write code from scratch using that page.  Maybe I shouldn't be asking such newbie questions, but I need example code to help me understand how it works. In this case, I may be asking someone to write the code for me. If so, I apologize in advance.

Comment: You really need to understand how to call the various APIs before embarking on projects that require them - simply copying someone else's code doesn't really help, unless you're doing a virtually identical task. Querying the ACL of a registry key is not the same as modifying the ACL of a registry key, and doesn't use the same procedural calls.

Comment: I agree, @JeffZeitlin

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is trying to do the same thing, I found this Sysinternals Application that does exactly what we need to do.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk

We'll include it with our app and call it.

Sample command we'll be using

**accesschk.exe -k users hklm\software\wow6432node\somekeyhere**